# My computer keeps typing the letter p repeatedly

Tags: windows-7

I'm using an HP laptop running Windows 7 Home Edition.

The moment I reach the login screen the computer automatically types "ppppppppp" in the password place, luckily I have fingerprint login to counter that.

The moment I login, it keeps acting as if I'm typing 'p' repeatedly. I tried removing the button and cleaning under it but it was no use. I've tried restarting, uninstalling the keyboard driver, but it was no use.

I can't go to Control Panel because the moment I get there, it starts typing "pppppp" in the search field and I'm unable to find anything.

I'm typing this from my phone because going anywhere on my laptop seems impossible.

Comment: Possibly significant:  The letter "p" is binary 1110000 in ASCII.

Comment: Turning on filter keys can offer temporary relief.

Answer (score 5):

Your **p** key is stuck down. You've already tried cleaning under it - try hitting it fairly firmly (not to the point of breaking the keyboard) to see if you can jar it loose. Also try the keys around it.

Comment: Also hitting the keys next to it is a good one. It really helps (sometimes). It won't help if the keyboard itself is broken. But they are relatively easy to replace and not too expensive. Or as Ramhound said: Disable it from bios and plug in an external one.

Comment: The HP website support section has step-by-step procedures for the replacement of keyboards (with pictures). They're well written because you're expected to replace it yourself under their general warranty.

Comment: @Ramhound and how are they going to open device manager if a key keeps being pushed? have you ever solved this one yourself?

Comment: @barlop - Why are you responding to a 7 year old comment?

Comment: AT Ramhound because it is irrelevant how old a comment is just like it is irrelevant how old a question is.  If somebody still uses the software in question eg windows 7 then the question is relevant and any comments are relevant, however old they are is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution -> remove battery from laptop for a while and reattach it.

I had the exact same issue, tried everything from defaulting factory setting, reformatting to install Window 7, but still had this issue. Also took off the "P" button from the keyboard and cleaned it thoroughly. I also uninstalled and re installed the keyboards from device manager, finally the removing and the cleaning of the battery is what worked. Just glad to have it working again.

Comment: Support the battery removal technique. I've seen residual power cause this issue on laptops before.

Comment: Yes, it really works!

Answer (score 1):

Push hard on the P key until it clicks or snaps (but don't break it). Maybe try spraying some canned air inside the keyboard. If nothing works, try removing your battery and putting it back in after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with "p" key. I didn't think it was a stuck key because I could add "p"s to the typing by hitting the p key.

I shut down the computer and opened it in safe mode. It worked fine. Did a system restore to the last restore point (two days previously) and now it works fine. We will have to see if it comes back.

I'm running a full virus scan, malwarebytes scan and backup just to e safe.